# SVN Attempted DAV:set error

Tags: svn

I'm attempting to do a commit in svn. Using the command line from the mac, with version 1.8.13.

`svn commit -m "merging community"`

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Attempted DAV:set operation could not be completed due to other errors.
```

This occurred after a large merge, with several conflicts that I manually resolved (though I'm not sure if that's at all relevant).

What does this error mean?